# Vaadin. Grid. Horizontal scrollbar disappears on browser window resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, vaadin, vaadin7

I face the following issue when using the latest Vaadin version.

I have a grid w/ some columns. I resize the browser window in a way to make the horizontal scroll bar appear. 
After that i move the scrollbar to the rightmost position. 
After that i maximize browser window and then minimize it back. 
And after that step the horizontal scroll bar disappears.

is it a bug in vaadin or anything else?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the SSCCE? Couldn't reproduce the error in my environment. What is your browser? What is the parent layout of your grid? Have you set a width for your grid or layout?

Comment: Hi! I can reproduce it at the official samples. Here is the link to the question i asked at the [Vaadin forum](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/12849324)

Comment: It also disappears after sorting columns.